# How to do partial fraction decomposition from a Laplace transform

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, partial-fractions

I am confused on how to do partial fraction decomposition from a Laplace transform.

If you have 
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} +3y = u_4(t)\cos(5(t-4)) \\ y(0)=0, y'(0)=-2$$

I can get to:
$$L(y) = \dfrac{se^{4s}}{(s^2+25)(s^2+3)}-\dfrac{2}{(s^2+3)}$$

But I don't know how to do the partial fraction decomposition. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(s) = \frac{se^{-4s}}{(s^2+25)(s^2+3)}-\frac{2}{(s^2+3)}$$
$$f(s) =se^{-4s}( \frac{1}{(s^2+25)(s^2+3)})-\frac{2}{(s^2+3)}$$
You can decompose the fraction this way:
$$f(s) =se^{-4s} \left( \frac{A}{(s^2+3)}+\frac{B}{(s^2+25)}\right)-\frac{2}{(s^2+3)}$$

You state :
$$ A(s^2+25) + B(s^2+3) = 1 $$
You find that:
$$A=-B=\frac 1 {22}$$
Therefore you have:
$$f(s) =\frac 1 {22} \left( \frac{se^{-4s}}{(s^2+3)}-\frac{se^{-4s}}{(s^2+25)}\right)-\frac{2}{(s^2+3)}$$
Apply inverse Laplace Transform on each term.

Comment: What would I set the A and B equal to? Like A(s^2+3) + B(s^2+15) = ?? and where would the se^4s go?

Comment: I added some lines @freshnovas I hope it's more clear...$A(s^2+25) + B(s^2+3) = 1$

Comment: @freshnovas you're welcome I think your exponent with exponential should be negative not positive. It's $e^{-4s}$